# How to sanitize global PHP variables in WordPress and WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, phpcs

I have small WP plugin, in it I have php Ajax handler file, where I can not use wordpress methods. In this file I do simple check:

```
isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'woocommerce_refund_line_items' !== strval($_REQUEST['action'])
```

When I try to pass WC phpcs standards I always get an error:

Detected usage of a non-sanitized input variable:

```
$_REQUEST['action']
(WordPress.Security.ValidatedSanitizedInput.InputNotSanitized)
```

Same happen for $_SERVER variables also.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched a bit? Read: [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) documentation: Everything is explained.

Comment: I search lot, an saw this page, but the methods there are no reachable from my file. If I start including all WP files may be I would be able to use them, but how much files I must include?

Comment: That are not methods, but WordPress functions… If Wordpress is not enabled on your php file, you should change your question title removing WordPress and WooCommerce everywhere. Then just search *"How to sanitize PHP $_REQUEST variable"* instead.

Comment: I put this title because the file is part of WP (WooCommerce) plugin, and I must cover PHPCS WC standards.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the answer for myself, I hope this could be in help for someone.
So, do not use separate ajax handler, just call default WP file - wp-admin/admin-ajax.php in your wp_localize_script.

Use the two hooks - wp_ajax_ and wp_ajax_nopriv_ (again in your index file) and all WP methods and functions will be available.

Comment: Nobody can't guess that with your question requirements and details as your question was unclear and your code not testable… So this is not really useful to anybody. Remember that: Questions seeking debugging help  must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions **without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).